# Using Hartigan's Dip Test to Calculate Bimodality

Tags: matlab, statistics

I am trying to use Hartigans Dip Test in matlab to calculate bimodality. I have data on halfwidths of action potentials and it looks to me like it has 2 peaks.(See examples attached). The results are pretty much the same for both cases.
Thanks!

[bimodal example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdY62.png)

here is the code i am using: nicprice.net/diptest

```
halfwidth = zeros(1,size(spikes,1));

  for j = 1:size(spikes,1)                 
    new = spikes(j,:);                     
    half = calc_halfwidth(new);

if isempty(half)==1
    halfwidth(j) = 0;
else
    halfwidth(j) = half;
end     
 end

[f,xi] = ksdensity(halfwidth);

[dip,p] = HartigansDipTest(f)
```

[unimodal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM8B9.png)

Comment: If you want debugging help you'll have to give us code that needs debugging.

Comment: here is the code i am using: http://www.nicprice.net/diptest/

Comment: Please don't add additional information as comments. [Edit] your question and include everything, including a [mcve].